# Google Cloud Functions - Deployment hangs for 5-10 minutes, then gives error "Deployment failure: Operation interrupted"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting errors when I try to deploy a Google Cloud Function. The process hangs for about 5-10 minutes and then an error appears:

"Deployment failure:
Operation interrupted."

I tried creating a new test function with nothing in it in two different projects of mine, both are timing out with that same error.

Anyone experiencing anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

There was an [incident related to Cloud Functions and Cloud Build](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-functions/19008) that began at 2019-09-24 13:00 and ended at 2019-09-24 18:15 (all times are US/Pacific).

It should be all good now. Please try to deploy your function again. 
In case it will not work for you. Please update your question to contain more information: minimum reproducible code, dependencies, timestamp.